# How do I make my SVN repository work across both windows & ubuntu on a dual boot PC?

Tags: windows, svn, ubuntu, netbeans

I have dual boot windows+ ubuntu PC. I created subversion repository for my netbeans project within windows 8 & used that for years but now I have started to use ubuntu  as well on the same PC. But When I open my netbeans project in ubuntu,  the project can't probably find my subversion repository(created by windows) & gives the following messages, I can access the repository however on , disk through ubuntu. How do I rectify this to enable proper communication between my project & repository while using  ubuntu.

```
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/DATA/PX10_DATA/SubversionRepository/PApp/src/main/webapp/js/essentials.js'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/DATA/PX10_DATA/SubversionRepository/PApp/src/main/webapp/js/essentials.js'
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/DATA/PX10_DATA/SubversionRepository/PApp/src/main/webapp/js/essentials.js'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/DATA/PX10_DATA/SubversionRepository/PApp/src/main/webapp/js/essentials.js'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running the repo as a file-based client, not as a proper server.

Run svnserve or mod_subversion inside apache and give that access to your repository files. Then your client connect to the server to perform all svn operations.

Obviously, you'll need to run both the Windows and the Linux version of svnserve to make this happen using the same repo - and might give you issues with line endings (ie the Ubuntu version of svnserve will not be able to read files created by the Windows version) but I think you might be able to jiggle settings and run the linux version under Windows which might be able to handle the linux-line endings correctly. Maybe.

This will solve your problem with the url - that looks like a Windows path and not a Linux one (ie the E: drive letter suggests this). You will not be able to re-wire this path (that is stored in the .svn directory DB for your working copy) safely.

However, the best answer is to run a little linux VM that contains your repo and a svn server, and mount it on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Well could I just synchronize my ubuntu & windows svn repository using an online repository hosting site? That's looks easier.. :)

Comment: way easier - its the "use a server based repo" but with a very distant server. IIRC Assembla had a decent (private repo for free) offering.